# Cannot unit test Material Menu using MatMenuHarness

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

Trying to test:

```
<button mat-button id="mainMenu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="main_menu" style="float: right; margin-left: 300px;"><fa-icon [icon]="faEnvelope"></fa-icon></button>

<mat-menu #main_menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item id="itemOne" (click)="reset(1)">Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item id="itemTwo" (click)="reset(2)">Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

as instructed in https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuHarness:

```
it('should test the main menu', async () => {
  const menu = await loader.getHarness<MatMenuHarness>(MatMenuHarness.with({selector: '#mainMenu'}));
  await menu.open();
  await fixture.detectChanges();
  const isOpen = await menu.isOpen();
  expect(isOpen).toBe(true);
  
  const items = await menu.getItems();
  expect(items.length).toBe(2);
});
```

However, it is failing on both conditions. The menu does not seem to be open and the items length is 0.

First, I had the id on the mat-menu tag and the loader was not able to query. Then I realized the loader is looking for '.mat-menu-trigger' which is set on the parent element instance.

I was wondering if there is something I am missing here.

And yes, I am exporting MatMenuModule in my test spec.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: According to https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses, the `with({selector: '#mainMenu'})` refers to the id, and not the reference. So `const menu = await ...` is actually your button, and not your `mat-menu`. Maybe try with `button.click()`, then expect menu to be opened.

Comment: At first, I was trying to get the menu by putting the id on the <mat-menu> tag. Then I realized the loader is looking for .mat-menu-trigger which is set on the parent element instance. Before the change it was not able to query the menu at all. Now it is, but looks like it is not going by ref as you said.

Answer (score 2):

first of all according to the harness functionality there is no need to call `detectChanges` function where you're using harness anymore, because it happens automatically under the hood. anyway if you wanna make this work **you have to import** `NoopAnimationModule` like below.

```
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatMenuModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
      ],
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  });

  it('should open the menu', async () => {
    const menu = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness.with({selector: `[data-testid="my-menu"]`}));
    expect(await menu.isOpen()).toBe(false);
    await menu.open();
    expect(await menu.isOpen()).toBe(true);
  });
```

and the template is like this

```
 <button  mat-button data-testid="my-menu"
          [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            Show Menu
  </button>

  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button
      *ngFor="let menu of menuItems"
      mat-menu-item
    >
      {{ menu.name}}
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, but I needed to change MatButtonHarness to MatMenuHarness, because the functions isOpen() and open() don't exist on MatButtonHarness. After that change, your suggestion worked perfectly! Thank you!